# Retrieve Linkedin user’s information

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, linkedin-api

I’m currently developing a NodeJS App and am intending to retrieve Linkedin user’s experience, education and skills. When doing so I get the error below. How can I avoid this error?

Here the workflow followed that leads to the error: http://3.14.113.64:4000/

```
InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
at _oauth2.get (/linkedin-connection/node_modules/passport-linkedin-oauth2/lib/oauth2.js:70:23)
at passBackControl (/linkedin-connection/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/linkedin-connection/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue of this library:
https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/issues/75

> this module that has not been updated to linkedin API 2.0 as reported in this issue

Switch this for fork:

```
npm install @sokratis/passport-linkedin-oauth2
```

And replace the require / import statement:

```
var LinkedInStrategy = require('@sokratis/passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;
```