# IBM Cloud App ID' s custom identity flow：InternalOAuthError occurs

Tags: ibm-cloud, linkedin-api, ibm-appid

I use IBM Cloud App ID' and I want to use LinkedIn as a provider.
However, "**InternalOAuthError**" occurs at the time of app approving.

There is a sample on the IBM Cloud blog.
[Sign In Your App Users With Any Identity Provider Using App ID](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/app-id-integrate-custom-identity)
I tried the sample app along this flow. Login to LinkedIn seems to have succeeded, but the following error occurred when app was approved.

```
InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
    at _oauth2.get (C:\xxx\AppIdCustomIdentity\node_modules\passport-linkedin-oauth2\lib\oauth2.js:70:23)
    at passBackControl (C:\xxx\AppIdCustomIdentity\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\xxx\AppIdCustomIdentity\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Please help!!

---

When I tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56329029/10422503),"InternalOAuthError" no longer occurs.
But another error has occurred.

```
Error: Failed to obtain tokens
    at Request.request [as _callback] (C:\xxx\AppIdCustomIdentity\node_modules\ibmcloud-appid\lib\token-manager\token-manager.js:118:13)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\xxx\AppIdCustomIdentity\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\xxx\AppIdCustomIdentity\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\xxx\AppIdCustomIdentity\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56329029/10422503), looks like the `passport-linkedin-oauth2` library has not been updated for the LinkedIn 2.0 APIs. Try using the fork suggested there

Comment: Thank you for your help.When I tried, "InternalOAuthError" did not occur anymore.
But another error has occurred.`Failed to obtain tokens`This is an error from ibmcloud-appid's token-manager.

Comment: If you are using the App ID v4 endpoints, using the latest SDK (6.0.0 and above) should solve the `Error: Failed to obtain tokens`

Comment: I checked the version of ibmcloud-appid, but it was the latest(6.0.0).
Do not know other possible causes?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stack trace it looks like the exception is coming from passport-linkedin-oauth2 module.

`at _oauth2.get (C:\xxx\AppIdCustomIdentity\node_modules\passport-linkedin-oauth2\lib\oauth2.js:70:23)`

Googling for `InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile +linkedin` gives a few options you might want to try.

Comment: Per this recent discussion at [GitHub](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/issues/24),Specified a specific profileField and scope.I tried, but I got the same error.